# Get VIEW ddl using query

Tags: sql, oracle, ddl, dbms-metadata

For database re-architecture I need to get DDL of each table and view in the database(Oracle). I don't want to go to property of each table/view and get SQL out of it in SQL Developer.

I successfully got DDL for table using-

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','Table_name','Schema_Name') 
  from dual;
```

But facing problem with VIEW and MVIEW. Could anyone provide commands/keywords for elements other than table.

Also, I want to export the result in an excel file with first column as `TableName` and second column as DDL.

Comment: Simply replace `TABLE` with `VIEW` and `Table_Name` with a `View_Name` in your `dbms_metadata.get_ddl()` call.

Comment: just be aware that text of view will/could be different from originally submitted.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov I tried the same. but its giving below error

ORA-31603: object "prs_talent_assessment_vw" of type VIEW not found in schema "oradba"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 5088
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 7589
ORA-06512: at line 1
31603. 00000 -  "object \"%s\" of type %s not found in schema \"%s\""
*Cause:    The specified object was not found in the database.
*Action:   Correct the object specification and try the call again.


But prs_talent_assessment_vw is present in db and oradba can access it.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Try the below query for view:

```
select text from ALL_VIEWS where upper(view_name) like upper(<view_name>);
```

For mviews:

```
select query from ALL_MVIEWS where upper(mview_name) like upper(<mview_name>);
```

Comment: This works for me `SELECT text FROM ALL_VIEWS WHERE VIEW_NAME = '<view_name>`

Answer (score 1):

For materialized views use:

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('MATERIALIZED_VIEW','MView_name','Schema_Name') 
  from dual;
```

See all supported object types here: [DBMS_METADATA: Object Types](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_metada.htm#BGBIEDIA)