# finding tables and columns used in oracle sql view

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

Is there any easy way to find the tables and columns used to create a view ?

i opened all the views and tried to find the tables and column used in it, but I feel I might have missed something. Is there any commands that displays all the columns and tables used in a view ?

Comment: Hi, there are a lot of ways to do this with SQL Developer. Here is a similar post with some reasonable and good answers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23515801/get-view-ddl-using-query

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open the view.

Open the Dependencies panel.

[image]

There's my list of tables.

Or...that's right, you wanted COLUMNS as well.

Do a SELECT * FROM for your view in the SQL Worksheet. Mouse over the SELECT keyword.

[image]

This invokes the SQL Text Expansion feature in the database. Note that if your underlying SQL includes wildcards, generating the DDL won't help you with column names.

If I click on the text of the view source after the mouse-over, you'll get the actual SQL in your worksheet.

For example this is what I get for 'SELECT * FROM EMP_DETAILS_VIEW'

```
SELECT "A1"."EMPLOYEE_ID"        "EMPLOYEE_ID",
       "A1"."JOB_ID"             "JOB_ID",
       "A1"."MANAGER_ID"         "MANAGER_ID",
       "A1"."DEPARTMENT_ID"      "DEPARTMENT_ID",
       "A1"."LOCATION_ID"        "LOCATION_ID",
       "A1"."COUNTRY_ID"         "COUNTRY_ID",
       "A1"."FIRST_NAME"         "FIRST_NAME",
       "A1"."LAST_NAME"          "LAST_NAME",
       "A1"."SALARY"             "SALARY",
       "A1"."COMMISSION_PCT"     "COMMISSION_PCT",
       "A1"."DEPARTMENT_NAME"    "DEPARTMENT_NAME",
       "A1"."JOB_TITLE"          "JOB_TITLE",
       "A1"."CITY"               "CITY",
       "A1"."STATE_PROVINCE"     "STATE_PROVINCE",
       "A1"."COUNTRY_NAME"       "COUNTRY_NAME",
       "A1"."REGION_NAME"        "REGION_NAME"
  FROM (
       SELECT "A7"."EMPLOYEE_ID"        "EMPLOYEE_ID",
              "A7"."JOB_ID"             "JOB_ID",
              "A7"."MANAGER_ID"         "MANAGER_ID",
              "A7"."DEPARTMENT_ID"      "DEPARTMENT_ID",
              "A6"."LOCATION_ID"        "LOCATION_ID",
              "A4"."COUNTRY_ID"         "COUNTRY_ID",
              "A7"."FIRST_NAME"         "FIRST_NAME",
              "A7"."LAST_NAME"          "LAST_NAME",
              "A7"."SALARY"             "SALARY",
              "A7"."COMMISSION_PCT"     "COMMISSION_PCT",
              "A6"."DEPARTMENT_NAME"    "DEPARTMENT_NAME",
              "A5"."JOB_TITLE"          "JOB_TITLE",
              "A4"."CITY"               "CITY",
              "A4"."STATE_PROVINCE"     "STATE_PROVINCE",
              "A3"."COUNTRY_NAME"       "COUNTRY_NAME",
              "A2"."REGION_NAME"        "REGION_NAME"
         FROM "HR"."EMPLOYEES"      "A7",
              "HR"."DEPARTMENTS"    "A6",
              "HR"."JOBS"           "A5",
              "HR"."LOCATIONS"      "A4",
              "HR"."COUNTRIES"      "A3",
              "HR"."REGIONS"        "A2"
        WHERE "A7"."DEPARTMENT_ID" = "A6"."DEPARTMENT_ID"
          AND "A6"."LOCATION_ID"    = "A4"."LOCATION_ID"
          AND "A4"."COUNTRY_ID"     = "A3"."COUNTRY_ID"
          AND "A3"."REGION_ID"      = "A2"."REGION_ID"
          AND "A5"."JOB_ID"         = "A7"."JOB_ID"
) "A1";
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Any way to find the columns used in those reference tables ?

Comment: @siddharththiagarajan updated my answer for you, sorry i missed that you mentioned columns as well

Answer (score 1):

`select * from all_dependencies where type = 'VIEW' and name = :your_view`